# jQuery animation more smoother?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, setinterval, smoothing, motion

problem evolves around

1. this random floating script allows only to make step movement
   as first to the left and then to the top, but in perfect it would be between the two
2. it is not smooth enought

I tried with easing plugin aslo

code is here:

```
function ran(min, max)
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
function moveIt()
{
    $(".circle").each(function() {
        x = ran(-3, 3);
        y = ran(-3, 3);
        pos = $(this).position();
        nowX = pos.left + x;
        nowY = pos.top + y;
        $(this).animate({"left": nowX}, {queue:false, duration:400, easing: 'linear'});
        $(this).animate({"top":  nowY}, {queue:false, duration:400, easing: 'linear'});
    });
}
setInterval(moveIt, 400);
```

Comment: So we know your problem, now what's your **question**?

Comment: how to get ridd of the zigg-zagg movement..... it is tiny ... but noticeable

Comment: possible duplicate of [Smoother Jquery Animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323138/smoother-jquery-animation)

Answer (score 2):

Updated your function with below.

1) Merge your 2 `animate()` invocation into 1

2) Replace the `setInterval()` using `animate()`'s own `success` callback to invoke recursively.

3) Replace the `setInterval()` using `delay()` method.

4) Try to 'smoothen' the animation by decreasing the delay between each loop. (Which was 400 set by you)

http://jsfiddle.net/6kxts/