# JQuery Animation jerky

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, smoothing

I have created an expanding DIV (contentright) and when the DIV expands. I am also expanding some images. When this animation is happening. It is jerky and not smooth. I know I am performing a few animations at once. But should I now be able to make this work smooth?

I updated to the latest jquery version 1.7.1 and that helped some.

Here you can see the page in action:
http://4wproductions.com/reels.php

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function() {
var Toggled = false;
if ($('#homepage').length > 0) {
  $('.mframe').css('display', 'none');
  $('.header').css('width', 0);
  $('.footer').css('width', 0);
  $('.hcontact').css('display', 'none');
  $('.fwlogo').css('display', 'none');
  $('.menuframe').css('height', 0);
  $('.menuframebg').css('backgroundColor', '#FFFFCC');
  $('.footerbg').css('background-color', '#FFFFCC');
  $('.footertext').css('display', 'none');
  $('.menuback').hide(0);
  $('.menuback').css('height', 0);
  $('.menuback').css('top', 445);
  $('.menudivide').css('width', 0);
  $('.menudividesocial').css('display', 'none');
  $('.menulink').css('display', 'none');
  $('.contentright').css('display', 'none');
  $('.contentcolumn').css('display', 'none');
  $('.focusmenu').css('display', 'none');
  $('.focusmenuf').css('display', 'none');
  $('.focusmenul').css('display', 'none');
  $('.adfooter').css('display', 'none');
  $('.copy').css('display', 'none');
  $('.mframe').fadeIn(450, 
  function() { $('.header').animate({width: '770px'}, 550);
  $('.footer').animate({width: '770px'}, 550, 
  function() { $('.menuframe').animate({height: '360px'}, 550);
  $('.footerbg').animate({backgroundColor: '#9FAD3D'}, 750);
  $('.footertext').fadeIn(750);
  $('.fwlogo').fadeIn(750);
  $('.hcontact').fadeIn(750,    
  function() { $('.menuback').show(0);
  $('.menuback').animate({height: '360px', top: '85px'}, 400); 
  $('.menudivide').animate({width: '259px'}, 450);
  $('.menuframebg').animate({backgroundColor: '#F1E190'}, 450, 
  function() { $('.menulink').fadeIn(450);
  $('.menudividesocial').fadeIn(450);
  $('.contentright').fadeIn(700, 
  function() { $('#column1').fadeIn(400, 
  function() { $('#column2').fadeIn(400, 
  function() { $('.focusmenu').fadeIn(800);
  $('.focusmenuf').fadeIn(800);
  $('.focusmenul').fadeIn(800, 
  function() { $('.adfooter').fadeIn(500, 
  function() { $('.copy').fadeIn(500)
  });
  });
  });
  });
  });
  });
  });
  });
  });
} else if ($('#about').length > 0) {
    $('.contentrighttext').css('display', 'none');
    $('#contenth1').css('display', 'none');
    $('.contentrighttext').fadeIn(2000);
    $('#contenth1').fadeIn(2000);
} else if ($('#services').length > 0) {
    $('#contenth1').css('display', 'none');
    $('#contentlmenu1').css('display', 'none');
    $('#contentlmenu2').css('display', 'none');
    $('#contentlmenu3').css('display', 'none');
    $('#contentlmenu4').css('display', 'none');
    $('#commercials').css('display', 'none');
    $('#commercialsimg').css('display', 'none');
    $('#filmsimg').css('display', 'none');
    $('#locationsimg').css('display', 'none');
    $('#marketingimg').css('display', 'none');
    $('#films').css('display', 'none');
    $('#locations').css('display', 'none');
    $('#marketing').css('display', 'none');
    $('#contenth1').fadeIn(1500, 
    function() { $('#contentlmenu1').slideToggle(400, 
    function() { $('#contentlmenu2').slideToggle(400, 
    function() { $('#contentlmenu3').slideToggle(400,
    function() { $('#contentlmenu4').slideToggle(400)
    });
    });
    });
    });
    $('#contentmenu1').click( function() {
        $('#contentlmenu2').slideToggle(400);
        $('#contentlmenu3').slideToggle(400); 
        $('#contentlmenu4').slideToggle(400);
        if (Toggled == false) {
            $(this).text('<');
            Toggled = true;
            $('#commercialsimg').fadeIn(800);
        } else {
            $(this).text('>');
            Toggled = false;
            $('#commercialsimg').hide(200);
            }
                $('#commercials').fadeToggle(600);
        });
        $('#contentmenu2').click( function() {
            $('#contentlmenu1').slideToggle(600); 
            $('#contentlmenu3').slideToggle(600); 
            $('#contentlmenu4').slideToggle(600);
            if (Toggled == false) {
                $(this).text('<');
                Toggled = true;
                $('#filmsimg').fadeIn(800);
            } else {
                $(this).text('>');
                Toggled = false;
                $('#filmsimg').hide(200);
            }
            $('#films').fadeToggle(600);
        });
        $('#contentmenu3').click( function() {
            $('#contentlmenu1').slideToggle(600); 
            $('#contentlmenu2').slideToggle(600); 
            $('#contentlmenu4').slideToggle(600);
            if (Toggled == false) {
                $(this).text('<');
                Toggled = true;
                $('#locationsimg').fadeIn(800);
            } else {
                $(this).text('>');
                Toggled = false;
                $('#locationsimg').hide(200);
            }
            $('#locations').fadeToggle(600);
        });
        $('#contentmenu4').click( function() {
            $('#contentlmenu1').slideToggle(600); 
            $('#contentlmenu2').slideToggle(600); 
            $('#contentlmenu3').slideToggle(600);
            if (Toggled == false) {
                $(this).text('<');
                Toggled = true;
                $('#marketingimg').fadeIn(800);
            } else {
                $(this).text('>');
                Toggled = false;
                $('#marketingimg').hide(200);
            }
            $('#marketing').fadeToggle(600);
        });
    } else if ($('#projects').length > 0) {
        $('#contenth1').css('display', 'none');
        $('#contentlmenu1').css('display', 'none');
        $('#contentlmenu2').css('display', 'none');
        $('#sc_graphicimg').css('display', 'none');
        $('#twosouls_graphicimg').css('display', 'none');
        $('#sc_graphic').css('display', 'none');
        $('#twosouls_graphic').css('display', 'none');
        $('#contenth1').fadeIn(1500, 
        function() { $('#contentlmenu1').slideToggle(400, 
        function() { $('#contentlmenu2').slideToggle(400)
        });
        });
        $('#contentmenu1').click( function() {
            $('#contentlmenu2').slideToggle(600); 
            if (Toggled == false) {
                $(this).text('<');
                Toggled = true;
                $('#sc_graphicimg').fadeIn(800);
            } else {
                $(this).text('>');
                Toggled = false;
                $('#sc_graphicimg').hide(200);
            }
            $('#sc_graphic').fadeToggle(600);
        });
        $('#contentmenu2').click( function() {
            $('#contentlmenu1').slideToggle(600); 
            if (Toggled == false) {
                $(this).text('<');
                Toggled = true;
                $('#twosouls_graphicimg').fadeIn(800);
            } else {
                $(this).text('>');
                Toggled = false;
                $('#twosouls_graphicimg').hide(200);
            }
            $('#twosouls_graphic').fadeToggle(600);
        });
    } else if ($('#reels').length > 0) {
        $('.bvideot').fadeOut(0);
        $('#contenth1').css('display', 'none');
        $('.vimeopreview').css('display', 'none');
        for (i=1; i <=tvideo; i++) {
        $('#v' + i).css('display', 'none');
        }
        $('#videoexpand').fadeOut(0);
        $('#videocollapse').fadeOut(0);
        $('#contenth1').delay(600).fadeIn(1500,
        function() {
        $('.vimeopreview').css('display', 'inline-block');
        $('.videoplayer').css('top', '120px');
        $('.videoplayer').css('left', '120px');
        $('.vimeoptext').css('width', '700px');
            $('.contentright').animate({
                top: '15px',
                right: '25px',
                width: '720px',
                height: '500px'
            }, 1500,
            function() {
                $('.contentright').css('border', '1px solid #CC9900');
                $('#videocollapse').fadeIn(500);
            });
            $('.contentrighttext').animate({
                width: '690px',
                height: '465px'
            }, 1500);
            $('.vimeopreview').animate({
                width: '125px',
                height: '110px'
            }, 1500);
            $('.videolink img').animate({
                width: '125px',
                height: '110px',
                'max-width' : '125px',
                'max-height' : '100px'
            }, 1500);
        });
        $('#videocollapse').click(
        function() {
            $('.contentright').css('border', 'none');
            $('.videoplayer').css('top', '45px');
            $('.videoplayer').css('left', '10px');
            $('.vimeoptext').css('width', '490px');
            $('.contentright').animate({
                top: '85px',
                right: '0px',
                width: '510px',
                height: '320px'
            }, 1500);
            $('.contentrighttext').animate({
                width: '480px',
                height: '285px'
            }, 1500);
            $('.vimeopreview').animate({
                width: '65px',
                height: '50px'
            }, 1500);
            $('.videolink img').animate({
                width: '65px',
                height: '50px',
                'max-width' : '65px',
                'max-height' : '50px'
            }, 1500);
            $('#videocollapse').fadeOut(500, 
            function() {
                $('#videoexpand').fadeIn(500)
            });
        });
        $('#videoexpand').click(
        function() {
            $('.videoplayer').css('top', '120px');
            $('.videoplayer').css('left', '120px');
            $('.vimeoptext').css('width', '700px');
            $('.contentright').animate({
                top: '15px',
                right: '25px',
                width: '720px',
                height: '500px'
            }, 1500,
            function() {
                $('.contentright').css('border', '1px solid #CC9900');
            });
            $('.contentrighttext').animate({
                width: '690px',
                height: '465px'
            }, 1500);
            $('.vimeopreview').animate({
                width: '125px',
                height: '110px'
            }, 1500);
            $('.videolink img').animate({
                width: '125px',
                height: '110px',
                'max-width' : '125px',
                'max-height' : '100px'
            }, 1500);
            $('#videoexpand').fadeOut(500,
            function() {
              $('#videocollapse').fadeIn(500);
            });
        });
        $('.videolink').hover(
        function() {
            var vt = this.id;
            $('#' + vt + 'text').css('display', 'block');
        },
        function() {
            var vt = this.id;
            $('#' + vt + 'text').css('display', 'none');
        });
        $('.videolink').click(
        function() {
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            var idn = id.match(/[0-9]+/);
            $('.vimeopreview').fadeOut(600, 
              function() { $('#v' + idn).fadeIn(600)
            });
        });
        $('.vlinkback').click(
        function() {
            var bid = $(this).attr("id");
            var bidn = bid.match(/[0-9]+/);
            $('#v' + bidn).fadeOut(600, 
              function() { $('.vimeopreview').fadeIn(600)
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: **HINT**: Use classes. Don't use jQuery for *everything*. CSS is your friend.

Comment: How do you ever plan on maintaining this?

Comment: It is alot of code. But I also have 7 different pages with independent animations. I broke up my code to only be active with that current page is active using #XXXXX.length>0. So if that page is active, only that script is active and working. Keeps me from having separate files. Everything is done is CSS. I am just animating the css changes.

Comment: This code was also designed to hide everything only if javascript is available. If it isn't, the page will still be displayed.

Comment: [I've posted an answer to your question as well as a similar demo here.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27372597/1922144)

Answer (score 0):

You could try switching everything inside the outer div to a percentage width, rather than a fixed one, and then just changing to outer div size.

It's still a lot of work for the browser, but it should improve things. It would also have the added bonus of not being *really* complicated!

Comment: I did that and converted my css to my use %. That works pretty good. But when I refresh the page. The first image doesn't resize properly. If I collapse my div and re-expand it. Then the first image looks the same compared to the other images. You can preview the % changes here:
[link](http://www.8balldzigns.com/4w)Testing Page