# How to fix a jerking effect during a jquery animation?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate

I have 4 divs each with different height arranged one after another.
When I click on any of these div it should slide left and hide, followed by adjacent divs sliding into former divs position. Currently sliding of divs is working but there is some kind of alignment problems which is not making the transition smooth

The working code is place in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kapilgopinath/aGxmY/3).

```
$(document).ready(function() {          
  $('.screenWrapper').click(function(){

    $("div.screenWrapper[data-messagetype='" + $('#msgStatusTitle')
      .html() + "']")
      .css({'opacity':1,'width':50});

    $("div.screenWrapper[data-messagetype='" + $('#msgStatusTitle')
      .html() + "']")
      .show();

    var msgTitle = $(this).attr('data-messageType');
    $('#msgStatusTitle').html(msgTitle);

    //$(this).hide();
    $(this).animate({
     'width'   : 0,
     'opacity' : 0
    }, 750, function() {
      $(this).hide();
      var cntr = 1;

      $('.screenWrapper').each(function(i, obj) {
        obj = $(obj);
        if(obj.css('display') != 'none') {
          obj.attr('class', 'screenWrapper block' + cntr);
          cntr++;
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

### How can I make the sliding smoother ?

Comment: Looks pretty smooth to me. Maybe it's your computer?

Comment: Same here, even in Firefox with ~50 tabs open, plus numerous other applications. Smooth animation (though the actual effect is sometimes glitchy as seen if you keep clicking on the leftmost div). What browser are you using?

Comment: The updated jsfiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/kapilgopinath/aGxmY/8/
The animation is smooth but as it slides the growth in height of the sliding divs gives a jumping effect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Smoother Jquery Animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323138/smoother-jquery-animation)